How to execute javascript in a secondary browser window with an external website in electronjs?
I am an electronjs/nodejs beginner and creating a project using electron-vite (vite+react+electron) to explore and learn more about it. I am already comfortable with vite+react.
The project that I am building is a bookmark app or could be a bookmark app.
I have a button that opens a popup modal. Inside the modal, there is a form with an input field (type URL) and a submit button, users can enter a URL and press submit. This URL is then processed by electron APIs and returns an object containing the page title, and a screenshot of the page which I display in UI. This is all happening with the help of IPC communication. Upon successful URL page fetching, the popup gets closed and the object containing the page title and the screenshot is displayed in the UI.
Now when I double clicks the bookmark card, A secondary windows open with the external URL for example https://github.com
// open external content url in new window const openURLInNewWindow = (url) => { const readUrl = window.open( url, '', 
maxWidth=2000;
maxHeight=2000
width=1200;
height=800;
contextIsolation=1;
nodeIntegration=0;
`
)
}`
Now, at this point, I want to write some javascript for this new window with external URL but unable to achieve this after many tries including eval.
I want to ask how to achieve this and is this a good practice? I want to create a fixed positioned button in the external window and do some further action action upon clicking it.
Let me know if you need to see any code in any file.
Thank you for any help
My Code Repository: https://github.com/HamzaAnwar1998/bookmark-app
I tried eval method by changing the html meta tag and allowing unsafe-eval but I don't want to use it and it also freezes the electron app when I execute alert("Hello") in the external website window, I don't know why.
I want to execute javascript in the external website window. I want to create a fixed positioned button in the external website and perform further action when clicked on it

No you cannot for security reason. You could make a bookmarklet but that is an extra click Only other alternative is to open the external website on your server and add the button there. However the page would then run in the scope of YOUR server
